# setting typeface globally Android

Tags: android

Hi i have a global Actions class that i am importing into my activities what i'm trying to do is to change the type face to any text within that activity.

heres my global Actions
 public final static void setTypeFace(Context someContext){

```
        Typeface face =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Verdana.ttf");
        }



    private static AssetManager getAssets() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    }
```

and heres where i'm trying to implement it in my activitiy

```
 GlobalActions.setTypeFace(this);
        super.setTypeface(GlobalActions.setTypeFace(face));
```

does anyone know how to do this or if it's even possible?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8954509/645270) might help. Someone suggested a custom View that extends TextView.

Comment: You can get the parent ViewGroup and loop over al View items. if view instanceof TextView -> setTypeface()

Comment: no, you can't set a font for the entire application

Comment: is there a way to set typeface in styles.xml?