# Change style of all TextViews in a layout

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a layout with many TextViews and a dark background, so I want to change the text color of **all** the TextViews to something light.

Is there a way to do it, beyond going to each one and setting `android:textColor='white'`?

[change font of all textviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954509/change-font-of-all-textviews) is asking a similar question, but it's from 2014, and there is no real answer there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as I was typing up the question.

You want to set the appearence of the TextViews via a style resource, not manually. Then, have the style value inherit from a different one, representing the entire layout.

```
<TextView ...
      android:textAppearance="@style/item_name"/>
<TextView ...
      android:textAppearance="@style/item_details"/>
```

in style.xml:

```
<style name="LayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#C0C0C0</item>
</style>
<style name="item_name" parent="LayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
<style name="item_details" parent="LayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience text size and color cannot be set as a linear layout attribute.
But you can set the theme. So define the theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="HeaderTitleTextViewTheme" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorSelectedItem</item>
</style>
```

and set it as the style of your layout:

```
<style name="ViewHeaderTitle">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/HeaderTitleTextViewTheme</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">48sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF5722</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

This will save you setting the style for every single TextView in the Layout